# Read in data from JSON file

Tags: json, elm

Say I have a JSON file located at http://www.randomurl.com/jobs.json, it looks like this:

```
{ "jobs": [
  { "task" : "turn burgers" ,
    "who" : "Anni" ,
    "place" : "Quick"}
  , 
  { "task" : "dishes" ,
    "who" : "Bob" ,
    "place" : "McDo"}
]}
```

I've made a decoder:

```
type alias Job = {
  task : String
, who : String
, place: String 
}

type alias Jobs  = List Job

decoder : Decoder Job
decoder =
  Decode.object3 Job
    (Decode.at ["attributes", "task"] Decode.string)
    (Decode.at ["attributes", "who"] Decode.string)
    (Decode.at ["attributes", "place"] Decode.string)

decoderColl : Decoder Jobs
decoderColl =
  Decode.object1 identity
    ("jobs" := Decode.list decoder)
```

How can I read in the file from that website using my decoder? I presume I need the Http package but I don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off - your `decoder` function is slightly off. There is no intermediate "attributes" object, so you can change it to this:

```elm
decoder : Decoder Job
decoder =
  Decode.object3 Job
    ("task" := Decode.string)
    ("who" := Decode.string)
    ("place" := Decode.string)
```

You are correct that you'll need the [elm-http](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/latest/) package. Using this, you can create an `Http.get` task which maps the result to an action.

As a basic example, let's make a button that pulls down the list of jobs from a url. We'll need a `GetJobs` action to trigger the HTTP request, and a `ShowJobs` action which will be trigged when the request returns successfully.

Assuming our Action type looks like this:

```elm
type Action
  = NoOp
  | GetJobs
  | ShowJobs (Maybe Jobs)
```

Then we can create a `getJobs` function that builds a task that can be run. For this simple example, we can use `Task.toMaybe` to suppress any HTTP or JSON decoding errors.

```elm
getJobs : Effects Action
getJobs =
  Http.get decoderColl jobsUrl
    |> Task.toMaybe
    |> Task.map ShowJobs
    |> Effects.task
```

In order to glue it all together, we'll use [StartApp](https://github.com/evancz/start-app) since it lets us use tasks and effects. Here's a working example that you can build locally, assuming that jobs.json exists in the same directory.

```elm
import Http
import StartApp
import Effects exposing (Effects,Never)
import Task
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder, (:=))

jobsUrl = "./jobs.json"

-- StartApp plumbing
app =
  StartApp.start { init = init, view = view, update = update, inputs = [] }

main =
  app.html

port tasks : Signal (Task.Task Never ())
port tasks =
  app.tasks


type Action
  = NoOp
  | GetJobs
  | ShowJobs (Maybe Jobs)

type alias Model =
  { jobs : Maybe Jobs }

init =
  ({ jobs = Nothing }, Effects.none)

update action model =
  case action of
    NoOp ->
      (model, Effects.none)
    GetJobs ->
      ({ model | jobs = Nothing }, getJobs)
    ShowJobs maybeJobs ->
      ({ model | jobs = maybeJobs }, Effects.none)

view address model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick address GetJobs ] [ text "Click to get jobs!" ]
    , viewJobs model.jobs
    ]

viewJobs maybeJobs =
  let
    viewJob job =
      li [] [ text ("Task: " ++ job.task ++ "; Who: " ++ job.who ++ "; Place: " ++ job.place) ]
  in
    case maybeJobs of
      Nothing ->
        div [] [ text "No jobs to display. Try clicking the button" ]
      Just jobs ->
        ul [] (List.map viewJob jobs)

-- This is the key to map the result of the HTTP GET to an Action
-- Note: Task.toMaybe swallows any HTTP or JSON decoding errors
getJobs : Effects Action
getJobs =
  Http.get decoderColl jobsUrl
    |> Task.toMaybe
    |> Task.map ShowJobs
    |> Effects.task

-- An alternative to Task.toMaybe which dumps error information to the console log
toMaybeWithLogging : Task.Task x a -> Task.Task y (Maybe a)
toMaybeWithLogging task =
  Task.map Just task `Task.onError` (\msg -> Debug.log (toString msg) (Task.succeed Nothing))

-- The Job type aliases from the question
type alias Job = {
  task : String
  , who : String
  , place: String 
}

type alias Jobs  = List Job

-- The updated Job decoder
decoder : Decoder Job
decoder =
  Decode.object3 Job
    ("task" := Decode.string)
    ("who" := Decode.string)
    ("place" := Decode.string)

decoderColl : Decoder Jobs
decoderColl =
  Decode.object1 identity
    ("jobs" := Decode.list decoder)
```

Comment: For some reason, when I try to compile your code, it runs out of memory, never had that before.

Comment: Found the problem, I needed to change `({ model | jobs = Nothing }, getJobs)` to `({ model | jobs <- Nothing }, getJobs)`. What's the difference between `=` and `<-`?

Comment: `<-` was changed to `=` in that context recently in version 0.16. Sounds like you just need the latest version of elm

Comment: Ah, ok. :)
I've tested your code and it works fine for local but it doesn't work for a file located online.

Comment: Is the file you're accessing on the same domain? You might be running into cross domain issues

Comment: No it's not on the same domain. I'm running my program localhost (with elm-reactor) and getting file from site online (f.e. http://example.com/jobs.json)

Comment: I've tampered the GET-request with Mozilla Firefox and it definitively came through but the content-type that was returned was `text/plain`. Shouldn't this be `application/json`? 

Some screens: http://imgur.com/9aXYOP7 , http://imgur.com/THqLUjX

Comment: @Stanko - perhaps it's time to replace `Task.toMaybe` with something that logs error information. I've updated the code with another function called `toMaybeWithLogging`. If you swap that with the `Task.toMaybe` call, it will log error information to the console log. Hope that helps you debug.

Comment: You were right, there was a cross-origin problem. I've got another URL and it works, thanks!