# Elm Json request not working?

Tags: json, elm

In Elm, you can use the `Json.decode` and `Http package` to request json data. My attempt was to work out a periodic lookup for emails ( [from this url](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14070433/temp.json) ). The timer operation does work (i tried it with with a simple counter).

I have used [this example](http://elm-lang.org/examples/zip-codes) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357902/read-in-data-from-json-file) as reference.

Now the types:

```
type alias Email = { title: String, ... }

type Action =
    NoAction
    | TickCounter -- TODO rem
    | AddEmails (List Email)
```

Then the main + state + actions ...

```
main: Signal Html
main = Signal.map (view actions.address) state

state: Signal Model
state = Signal.foldp update makeEmptyModel input

-- handle inputs (merging signals)
input : Signal Action
input =
    Signal.mergeMany
    [ actions.signal
    -- , other actions
    , Signal.map checkForNewMails (Time.every (Time.minute / 6.0) ) -- TODO precise timer (quick test)
    ]

actions: Signal.Mailbox Action
actions = Signal.mailbox NoAction

update: Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
case action of
    NoAction -> model
    TickCounter -> { model | count = model.count + 1 }
    AddEmails newMails -> { model | emails = newMails }


checkForNewMails: Time -> Action
checkForNewMails t =
    let mails = startGettingEmailData
    in TickCounter -- TODO replace with AddEmails using mails
```

The `TickCounter` is an Action, which i have used to test my timing operation. But the problem is `startGettingEmailData`. It uses the next snippet, but it doesn't fire any JSON request (i have checked it through the console). Once that has been resolved, i can convert `mails` to an action so that i can add the emails in the model.

```
-- url to json
jsonUrl = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14070433/temp.json"

-- get emails
startGettingEmailData: Task Http.Error (List Email)
startGettingEmailData = Http.get emailJsonDecoder jsonUrl 

emailJsonDecoder: Json.Decoder (List Email)
emailJsonDecoder =
    let makeEmail = Json.object4
            (\ti fr da bo -> makeNewEmail -1 ti fr da bo )
            ("title" := Json.string)
            ("from" := Json.string)
            ("date" := Json.string)
            ("body" := Json.string)
    in
        "emails" := Json.list makeEmail
```

Is there a problem with my code ? If not, then is there a way to check the Http.Error content ? (Maybe the problem lies not in my code, but in the network, but i can access the dropbox file by browser...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for `checkForNewMails` doesn't actually do anything with `mails`, so it never gets invoked. The `let` statement doesn't make any calls, it only lets you define one-off functions within the body of a larger function. Since the `in` portion merely returns `TickCounter`, then it means this function only ever returns `TickCounter` and does nothing else.

Furthermore, `startGettingEmailData` is returning a `Task`, which means it only gets invoked when in a port. You can't use it in a function that only returns an `Action`, because it would never get run.

You'll instead want to write a `port` that triggers on a timer, then creates a `Task` which polls your url, then maps the response of that GET request to an Action, calling the `actions` mailbox. You can use [`Task.onError`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Task#onError) to write a simple error handler, which could forward an error message to your view by creating an `Error String` constructor on your Action type.

Here's an example:

```elm
getEmailData _ =
  let
    request =
      Http.get emailJsonDecoder jsonUrl
        |> Task.map AddEmails
  in
    request
      `Task.onError` (\err -> Task.succeed (Error (toString err)))
      `Task.andThen` (\action -> Signal.send actions.address action)

port getEmails : Signal (Task a ())
port getEmails =
  Signal.map getEmailData (Time.every (Time.minute / 6.0) )
```

The above code will cause the URL to be retrieved, parsed, then, on success, it will trigger you `actions` mailbox and cause an update of the view. If there is an error, it will send the new action of `Error` with a message, which you should handle in the view. (You'll have to add `Error String` to the `Action` union type and handle it in the model, update, and view functions).

Comment: how can i trigger a port ? Can you give an example ?

Comment: Thanks ! It seems that you can bind signals to ports that it is able to operate on itself, only sending signals if there is data. I had a misconception though, i thought that i had to include JavaScript if i read [this](http://elm-lang.org/guide/interop#ports).